# How to put path of the app.py file in the command 'python -m uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0' considering app.py lies inside a folder named 'test'

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy my fastapi code on azure webapp. I want to write the startup command in the webapp configuration to run the fastapi. Ideally this command should be `python -m uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0` but since my app.py file is not the root folder but in another folder named 'test', I tried writing the command as: `python -m uvicorn --chdir test app:app --host 0.0.0.0` and `python -m uvicorn test.app:app --host 0.0.0.0` and `python -m uvicorn test/app:app --host 0.0.0.0` but none of them is working. What should I do? Am I doing something wrong? I get an 'application error' on the webapp when I put any of these commands in the starup.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LFwV.png)

I also tried writing `python -m uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0` in a startup.sh file and added it to the startup command field in azure webapp but that also does not work.[startup command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1QPr.png)

I think the problem is it is unable to detect uvicorn. But I am installing uvicorn through requirements.txt file in my azure devops deployment pipeline. What could be going wrong here?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMHlj.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, I looked up uvicorn and I'm not exactly sure if it'll work in a blessed image. There may be some additional setup/configuration that has to be done.

But here's what I would try, follow [Using GitHub Actions for Python Applications - Azure App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/12/11/cicd-for-python-apps.html) and configure your pipeline as illustrated. Make sure you have `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` set to true. This will tell the platform to download and install what's in **requirements.txt**. If there are any additional setup (I don't know much about uvicorn) but you can do that in the `POST_BUILD_COMMAND`, see [Customize build automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-build-automation) for details. If your app.py *needs* to be in /test (not sure why but...) the startup command should look something like `uvicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timout 600 --chdir test app:app`. If that doesn't work, have look at the [app logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) and checkout [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#troubleshooting) for most common issues and fixes.

If none of that is helpful, you can also configure your own [custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?tabs=dotnet&pivots=container-linux-vscode) with uvicorn installed and configured to your liking and push the image to your web app.